# Master/Detail DataGrid. How to access Detail DataGrid to set ItemsSource?

Tags: xaml, silverlight, datagrid, master-detail

In a typical Master/Detail situation...

I have a DataGrid. The ItemsSource of this DataGrid is set in the Completed event of a WCF call - (grdMaster.ItemsSource = e.Result) - where the x:Name of the grid is grdMaster. This is all 100%.

However, when adding a Detail Datagrid inside the master grids DataTemplate and naming it appropriately... my codebehind does not recognise the detail grid. So plainly put, I cannot set the ItemsSource of grdDetail like I do with grdMaster.

Depending on the Master item selected, I need to do a WCF call to get the appropriate Details.

Answer (score 2):

Depending on how you are being notified that an item is being selected for expansion you will need to find the row the user is in:

```
DataGridRow row = DataGridRow.GetRowContainingElement(...);
```

and update the row details visibility:

```
row.DetailsVisibility = Visibility.Visible;
```

Those details aside, you need to create a style for the details rows -- which is wired to an event you can listen to:

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="DetailsRowTemplate">
    <StackPanel>
        <Border BorderBrush="{StaticResource BlackBrush}" BorderThickness="0,2,0,0" Padding="0" >
            <data:DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding DummyResultsView}" AutoGenerateColumns="False"
                            LoadingRow="DataGrid_LoadingRow" 
                            CanUserResizeColumns="False" 
                            CanUserReorderColumns="False"
                            HeadersVisibility="None"
                            IsReadOnly="True">
            </data:DataGrid>
        </Border>
    </StackPanel>
</DataTemplate>
```

which is set as the RowDetailsTemplate for your grid:

Within the LoadingRow event you can obtain a reference to which data context is involved, and save a reference to the child data grid so that after a WCF call you can set the ItemsSource:

```
private void DataGrid_LoadingRowDetails(object sender, DataGridRowDetailsEventArgs e)
{
    List<DataGrid> detailElements = e.DetailsElement.GetChildrenByType<System.Windows.Controls.DataGrid>().ToList();

    var itemSelected = e.Row.DataContext;

    if (detailElements.Count > 0)
    {
        DataGrid detailsDataGrid = detailElements[0];

        // save a reference so the ItemsSource can be set later....
        this.DataGrid = detailsDataGrid;

        this.Model.InitializeDetailsList(detailsDataGrid, itemSelected);
    }
}
```

Hope that helps,